# How to add a list to DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, sql-update, where-clause, common-table-expression

I have data that follows:

```
vocab   phonetictranscription_bre   phonetictranscription_ame
little           ˈlɪtl                       ˈlɪtəl
settle           ˈsɛtl                       ˈsɛtəl
...
```

If the word is in the list below, I want to change every 't' symbol in phonetictranscription_ame with the 'd' symbol

```
['little', 'better', 'pretty', 'matter', 'letter', 'committee', 'pattern', 'battle', 'attitude', 'settle', 'bottom', ...]
```

So I thought it could be done with a for loop like:

```py
for element in list:
     UPDATE table_name
     SET phonetic = REPLACE (phonetic, 't', 'd')
     WHERE vocab = element
```

would work but I couldn't find any information regarding creating a list on SQLite DB browser. I couldn't find anything online either.

Expected outcome:

```
vocab   phonetictranscription_bre   phonetictranscription_ame
little           ˈlɪtl                       ˈlɪdəl
settle           ˈsɛtl                       ˈsɛdəl
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a CTE that returns the list and use in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement:

```
WITH cte(vocab) AS (VALUES
 ('little'), ('better'), ('pretty'), ('matter'), ('letter'), ('committee'), 
 ('pattern'), ('battle'), ('attitude'), ('settle'), ('bottom') 
)
UPDATE table_name AS t
SET phonetictranscription_ame = REPLACE(t.phonetictranscription_ame, 't', 'd')
WHERE t.vocab IN cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d4bc81b0728d0ef5e2624be110269030).